# Sequelize and defaultScope with Models associated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize with Express, and Node js and I am trying to define defaultScope for Models.
Card and Tag have a Many To Many association.
Here are Models definitions and addScope

```
// Models Associations

// ONE TO MANY
List.hasMany(Card, {
  as: "cards",
});
Card.belongsTo(List, {
  as: "list",
});

// MANY TO MANY
Card.belongsToMany(Tag, {
  as: "tags",
  through: "card_has_tag",
  updatedAt: false,
});
Tag.belongsToMany(Card, {
  as: "cards",
  through: "card_has_tag",
  updatedAt: false,
});

// SCOPES
Card.addScope("defaultScope", {
  include: {
    association: "tags",
  },
});

List.addScope("defaultScope", {
  include: {
    association: "cards",
    include: "tags",
  },
});

// What I would like to implement
// If I comment lines below => List and Card queries are working
Tag.addScope("defaultScope", {
  include: {
    association: "cards",
  },
});
```

I would like to print by default all related infos with associated relations.

I want to  get this info when I execute a sequelize query for each model.

1. LISTS with associated :

- cards
- tags

2. CARDS with associated:

- tags

3. TAGS with associated :

- cards

I manage to get 1 & 2, but when I add `Tag.addScope`nothing is working anymore.

When I change `defaultScope` by another string by defining a scope `all` (for example) , and when I use `model.scope("all").findAll()`, this is working, but it is not what I would like to do becaue I want to use defaultScope to have a default behavior so I don't have to specify scope in queries command like (findAll...)

Is there a way I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to set it up results in an endless recursion, you simply can't have it like that.

If you set it up like that and query `Card` it will include `Tag` which will include `Card` which will include `Tag` and so on until you get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

There is a workaround you can use, which is to add another scope which includes nothing, then specify that scope for the model in the `defaultScope`.

```js
Tag.addScope("noInclude", {});
Card.addScope("noInclude", {});

Tag.addScope("defaultScope", {
  include: [
    {
      model: Card.scope("noInclude"),
      as: "cards"
    }
  ]  
});

Card.addScope("defaultScope", {
  include: [
    {
      model: Tag.scope("noInclude"),
      as: "cards"
    }
  ]
});
```

This should give you the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes it is what I understood that it generates something like an infinite loop/recursion, but I didn't manage to solve it, or to limit recursion...

Comment: @badelgeek I've updated my answer with a workaround you should be able to use.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your help, it is working, nice workaround